# Process tracker - formulas, vba or conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I just started to make an Excel ”tracker”, so I can follow how it goes with a process. I have 6 steps in all that I need to track: Step 1, Step 2, Step 3, Step 4, Step 5 and Step 6. I have also a start and deadline date. 
Step 1-3 I estimated to be finished 20 days before deadline. Step 4 need to be finished 6 days before deadline, Step 5 5 days before deadline.

I need the tracker to show ”Semi-behind” if these is not achieved. If the process is going after the plan Column N just have to show “On track”. If the deadline date is passed, then Column have to say “Behind”. If the difference between start date and deadline date is less than 20 days, column N have to say “ASAP”.

Do you have a good idea how I can make this? With formulas, vba or just conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this formula.
Let's says you put Start Date in column L2, ProcessDate in column M2 Deadline in column N2 and the formula in column O2 would be like this:

```
=IF(AND((N2-M2)<20,(N2-M2)>0),"ASAP",IF(M2>L2,"On Track",IF(M2>N2,"Behind","Semi-behind")))
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hey Adhy, thanks for answer. I need to decide under the condition that i for example have reached Step 4.
Br

Comment: Column M is the process date. So, I think you can add formula in this column to get Step 4 date.